# Bootstrap SideNav on right side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this SideNav, but it's on left side and I need it on right side, how can i do this?
I tried do this with `position: relative;` but it's crashed sidebar (stays only brand on left side)

Codepen DEMO: http://codepen.io/vertisan/pen/xOLPXy

Comment: you want open it from right?

Comment: Yes, on right side of page.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Maharkus/pen/OXxdEB does this help? It opens from the left, but on the right side of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add below css

```
.navbar-fixed-bottom, .navbar-fixed-top{
   left:auto;
}
```

there is `left:0px` is applying from the `bootstrap` css file.
 if not applying try to add `!important`

Answer (score 1):

just add the following style.

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    left: auto;
}
```

This should do the trick and overwrite the left:0 that is present.

Hope this works for u.